# Julia matrix operation

Tags: matrix, julia, operation

I am looking for a matrix operation. But not sure if there is an existing operation for it.

Ex:P=[1 2 ; 3 4] and Q=[5 6 ; 7 8]

```
[P ; Q] @ [P ; Q] => [P*P ; P*Q ; Q*P ; Q*Q]
```

@ is the operation that I am looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: Just confirming, this is the outer product, right? If so, `a*b'` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you want `[P*P ; P*Q ; Q*P ; Q*Q]` as the output and not `[P*P P*Q; Q*P Q*Q]`, or even more likely, `[P*P' P*Q' ; Q*P' Q*Q']`?

Comment: @Mason Yes, [P*P ; P*Q ; Q*P ; Q*Q] is the output that I'm looking for. But I guess there's no operation for it, not pretty sure. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your custom operator such as:

```
function ⊗(a::Matrix,b::Matrix)
    h1 = Int(size(a,1)/2)
    P1 = @view a[1:h1,:]
    Q1 = @view a[h1+1:end,:]
    h2 = Int(size(b,1)/2)
    P2 = @view b[1:h2,:]
    Q2 = @view b[h2+1:end,:]
    [P1*P2 ; P1*Q2 ; Q1*P2 ; Q1*Q2]
end
```

And now use it!

```
julia> [P ; Q] ⊗ [P ; Q] == [P*P ; P*Q ; Q*P ; Q*Q]
true
```

Perhaps you need to add checking the sizes etc.
You might also want to have and additional operator function ⊗(a::Tuple{Matrix,Matrix},b::Tuple{Matrix,Matrix}) so you do not need to merge `P` and `Q` matrices and then later decomposing them.

Comment: `Int(n/2)` will error unless `n` is an even number (and it's slower, too). Use integer division, `div(n, 2)` or `n ÷ 2` (or `n >> 1`) instead. It is rarely necessary to do conversions like that, also when doing round/floor etc. write `round(Int, x)` instead of `Int(round(x))`, etc.